# XSLT removing unnecessary element

Tags: xslt

i am trying to write an xslt code that will check whether the description element exist or not if it exist then it will show the description element but if it does not exist then it should not show the description element.but my code below still show  element although there is no value in it.how can we code it so that it wont show out the description element if there is no description for a services.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


   <xsl:template match="Service">
     <xsl:element name="equipment">
      <xsl:if test="description !='' ">
          <xsl:value-of select="description" />
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="not(description)">
      </xsl:if>
     </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

as there is the an empty equipment element being returned.i want it to return only the first 2 equipment element that is not empty.

Comment: yes, the out put should only append <description> element to those services that have description.

Comment: that output is not valid xml.. need single root element

Comment: silly mistake made by myself, removing the element itself ok.thanks for all the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//Service"/>
  </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Service">
      <xsl:if test="description !='' ">
           <xsl:element name="equipment">
          <xsl:value-of select="description" />
     </xsl:element>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

or

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//Service"/>
  </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="Service">
      <xsl:if test="child::description[text()]">
       <xsl:element name="equipment">
          <xsl:value-of select="description" />
            </xsl:element>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated solution is follows; please check

```
  <xsl:template match="Services">
    <xsl:for-each select="Service">
      <xsl:if test="count(description) &gt; 0 and description!=''">
        <equipment>
          <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
        </equipment>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: this is not what i am trying to do.i will try expand my code.and maybe you can understand what i am trying to do.

Comment: Can you please update your question with desired output xml for the given input xml?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<!-- place <result /> as root to produce wellformed XML -->
<xsl:template match="/">
  <result><xsl:apply-templates /></result>
</xsl:template>

<!-- rewrite those <Service /> that have a <description /> -->
<xsl:template match="Service[./description]">
  <equipment><xsl:value-of select="description" /></equipment>
</xsl:template>

<!-- remove those who do not -->
<xsl:template match="Service[not(./description)]" />
</xsl:transform>
```